# Как вычислить конечную дату при наведении react-date-range

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, datepicker

Я использую в проекте react-date-range и столкнулся с проблемой, нужно высвечивать окно где написано "Х ночей" над конечной датой при наведении, т.е. образно я кликнул на 9 сентября и когда начинаю вести мышь на 10,11,12...Х дату на этих датах подсвечивается к-во ночей.

Вот мой компонент:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
import ru from 'date-fns/locale/ru';
import React from 'react';
import { DateRange } from 'react-date-range';
import 'react-date-range/dist/styles.css';
import 'react-date-range/dist/theme/default.css';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import store from '../../../data/store';

const screenSmall = window.innerWidth > 1220;

const DatePickerBlock = ({
    setDatepicker,
    datepicker,
    open,
    updateActiveElement,
}) => {
    const night = {
        nights: Math.ceil(
            (datepicker[0].endDate - datepicker[0].startDate) / 86400000
        ),
    };
    const days = document.querySelectorAll('.rdrDay');
    const dayNightsDiv = document.createElement('div');
    dayNightsDiv.className = 'dayNights';

    let isAnyDayHovered = false;

    for (let i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
        days[i].addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
            if (days[i].classList.contains('rdrDayHovered')) {
                console.log(1);
                dayNightsDiv.innerHTML = `${Math.ceil(
                    (datepicker[0].endDate - datepicker[0].startDate) / 86400000
                )}`;

                days[i].appendChild(dayNightsDiv);
                isAnyDayHovered = true;
            } else {
                const dayNightsElements =
                    days[i].querySelectorAll('.dayNights');
                dayNightsElements.forEach((element) => {
                    element.remove();
                });
            }
        });
    }

    document.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
        if (!isAnyDayHovered) {
            dayNightsDiv.remove();
        }
    });
    return (
        <div className={`DatePicker ${open && 'active'}`}>
            <div
                className={`DatePicker-shadow ${open && 'active'}`}
                onClick={updateActiveElement(1)}
            ></div>
            <div className="wrapper">
                <div className="DatePicker__block">
                    <DateRange
                        onChange={(item) => {
                            setDatepicker([item.selection]);
                            store.setDataBooking('datepicker', [
                                item.selection,
                            ]);
                        }}
                        moveRangeOnFirstSelection={false}
                        ranges={datepicker}
                        months={screenSmall ? 3 : 1}
                        direction="horizontal"
                        showMonthAndYearPickers={false}
                        showDateDisplay={false}
                        monthDisplayFormat="MMMMMMMM yyyy"
                        locale={ru}
                        preventSnapRefocus={true}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default DatePickerBlock;
```

В данный момент for ставит над датой на которую мы навелись блок, но там как ожидалось NaN
Т.к. конечной даты ещё просто не существует, как ее получать при наведении?